# Potential difference of a resistor

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, batteries

The resistor causes a potential difference across its end points but nowhere is written what is the direction of this difference. Is it from positive to negative or negative to positive.

I will take a help of this question to be more clear.

[image]
In this circuit (neglect ammeter's resistance), The potential difference of resistor would be 20V. But what is potential (relative, not absolute) at points A and B? Is A at zero potential and B on 20V potential or is it opposite?
Either way, the answer to this question can proof whether the current flows from positive to negative terminal of a cell or vice-versa.

So my question in general is, live wire is connected to positive terminal or negative terminal?

Then if we replace the cell by an AC source, what will be the potential at A and B in the question? Would A be at zero potential or B will be at zero potential?

Answer (score 2):

In the symbol used to represent the battery in your circuit, the longer line represents the positive terminal of the battery.  That means that the potential increases from B to A. We normally calculate with positive current, assumed to flow from the + terminal of a DC power source, through the external circuit to the – terminal.  Measurement of the Hall effect tell us that the actual flow is electrons going from – to +.

Comment: Why it increases from B to A? Is it because current flows from postive to negative? But I thought that only conventional current flows from positive to negative but this potential increase from B to A seems to proof that real current itself flows from positive to negative.

Comment: Current flows from a point of high potential to one of low potential. But something, such as a battery, has to provide that potential in the first place.

Comment: @Guy Inchbald If terminal of battery connected to B is at -10V relative potential and terminal connected to A at +10V relative potential then relative potential at A is +10V and at B is -10V. Electrons will flow from -10V to +10V and conventional current will flow from +10V to -10V . But which is live or neutral wire?

Comment: You have not said what these 10V values are relative to. A relative potential is always between two points. You would have to state both points or your number is meaningless. There is no "live" or "neutral" wire here, they have not been specified. You must keep such things out of your thinking. There is no reference point here. So there are no absolute potentials. No any, not by any name. None. You really do need to grasp this.

Comment: @GuyInchbald we can define any one point in the circuit to have whatever potential we want. Choosing an arbitrary point in the circuit as "ground" is just a special case of that.

Comment: @ThePhoton That is a different principle from the one being asked about here. We used to set the DC negative line to +10 kV relative to ground, which is hardly relevant here.

Comment: @GuyInchbald okay these 10V potentials are relative to ground. Now what will be potential at point A and B according to my last comment or still something to be corrected?

Comment: To get + and – 10 volts at the terminals of the battery, the “ground” would have to be connected (or chosen) at the center of the resistor (assuming the ammeter has no resistance).

Answer (score 0):

In the circuit you have drawn, there is no absolute potential value. There is only the *potential difference* of 20V supplied by the battery. This is what appears across the resistor.

Absolute values are always relative to some point on the circuit which is designated 0V. Often, that is the potential at a Ground or Earth point.

If no such point is identified, as here, then there is no designated 0V and all potentials are relative to each other.

So we say that there is a potential difference across the resistor of 20V, and the battery + and - terminals show you the polarity or direction of that difference.

Comment: So what will be the relative potential at A and B?

Comment: That is given by the polarity of the battery terminals. The potential does not change along (ideal) wires or through (ideal) ammeters. Which terminal is A connected to? Which terminal is B connected to?

Comment: A is connected to positve terminal and B to negative terminal of cell.

Comment: That was a hint, those questions were for you to ask yourself. Here is another hint: the answer is written on your diagram, I have already told you where, in fact it is the only answer written on your diagram. See also the first paragraph of my main answer. You need to think for yourself just a *little* bit.